# Hide particular airwires/nets in eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers

Is it possible to hide particular airwires in eagle, without hiding all of them?

So if there's a net I am not currently interested in, but it has a lot of connections, confusing where other airwires go, I can hide it. I am wanting to do this for GND and +V but, don't want to run ratsnest resulting in a pour.

Any ideas?

Comment: I avoid this problem by doing the power and ground connections *first*. They can always be tweaked later if the signal routing requires it, but they really should be your first priority.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep, and it's pretty straightforward. Just click on the Info button [image], select the airwire you want to hide, and click on the "Airwires hidden" checkbox. All airwires on that same net will be hidden.
[image]

Obviously this is a do-at-your-own-risk. You'll have to remember to explicitly un-hide the airwire later to do the routing.

Comment: how do you un-hide the airwire later if it is hidden?

Comment: Type "ratsnest <signal name>" in the command field at the top to unhide a specific signal. To unhide all airwires, you can use a wildcard: "ratsnest *"

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

```
ratsnest ! GND 
(Or ratsnest ! [SignalName])
```